# Can't login to dovecot using gmail as an email client

Tags: email, ssl, ssl-certificate, dovecot, imap

I've used this installation
[configure-email-server-using-postfix-dovecot](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassasin)

When I try to use gmail as the email client (connecting to my server through port 993) I get this error

```
Unable to establish secure SSL connection to email.example.com
```

My `dovecot -n` output

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = maildir:/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
mail_privileged_group = mail

passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf.ext
  driver = sql
}
protocols = imap lmtp
service auth-worker {
  user = vmail
}
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0666
    user = postfix
  }
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    mode = 0600
    user = vmail
  }
  user = dovecot
}
service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
    port = 0
  }
}
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = required
ssl_cert = </etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/var/mail/vhosts/%d/%n
  driver = static
}
```

When I check the logs I see this

```
 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 25 secs) ....
```

PS: the cert is a self signed.

Comment: Thanks for actually using your domain, makes life a lot easier. That said, when you say you "use gmail" do you mean you sent a message through gmail to your server? If so, can you post the relevant lines from your mail log?

Comment: no. I mean using gmail as an email client. Trying to connect to my server through 993

Comment: You do realise that GMAIL only supports POP3 for checking/importing mail from other email accounts? enable POP3 over SSL on port 995...

Comment: gmail does support sending through other mail servers via TLS/SSL (authenticated), but not checking mail over IMAP.

Comment: ok. Next I've tried thunderbird. Trying imap on 993 but I get the same error in my syslog

Comment: What authentication methods have you tried in TB?

Answer (score 2):

As per @HBruijn's comment, Gmail only supports retrieving email through POP3, not IMAP. This has been confirmed on their [product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/b0v5HHlqbHs)

Both Gmail and Dovecot support POP3 over SSL, which you should be able to use by opening port 995 on your firewalls, and directing Gmail at it.

Answer (score 1):

for use pop3 with ssl on gmail to fetch mail

**FOR CLIENT SIDE:**

1. enter fqdn
2. enter your full email address
3. select port 995
4. select use ssl

**FOR SERVER SIDE:**

SSL certificate must:

- match domain name of server  (FQDN)
- in your case email.example.com not example.com
- be valid
- not self signed

put this in dovecot config and see logs **i'll bet it's certificate issue**

```
# Log unsuccessful authentication attempts and the reasons why they failed.
auth_verbose = yes

# In case of password mismatches, log the attempted password. Valid values  are
# no, plain and sha1. sha1 can be useful for detecting brute force password
# attempts vs. user simply trying the same password over and over again.
auth_verbose_passwords = yes

# Even more verbose logging for debugging purposes. Shows for example SQL
# queries.
auth_debug = yes

# In case of password mismatches, log the passwords and used scheme so the
# problem can be debugged. Enabling this also enables auth_debug.
auth_debug_passwords = yes

# Enable mail process debugging. This can help you figure out why Dovecot
# isn't finding your mails.
mail_debug = yes

# Show protocol level SSL errors.
verbose_ssl = yes
```

> @downvoter: Care to explain your vote?